# Angular 2 how to navigate to child route with optional parameters

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, angular2-template

Hi I am opening child 'add-experience' view in parent 'my-account' which is working fine with

```
<button type="button" [routerLink]="['/my-account', {outlets: {'editDetail':['add-experience']}}]" class="btn btn-primary relative waves-light" (click)="basicModal.show()" mdbRippleRadius>add experience</button>
```

Now I want to pass parameters like id of children 'add-experience'
please let me know how it can be done ?

```
{ path: 'my-account',  component: MyAccountComponent, canActivate:[AuthService],
  children:[
      { path: 'add-experience', component: AddExperienceComponent, 
        canActivate:[AuthService], outlet: 'editDetail',

            children:[
                 {path: ':id', component: AddExperienceComponent, 
                  canActivate:[AuthService], outlet: 'editDetail'}
      ] }
    ]
  }
```

Comment: I haven't seen named outlets working when used in routes configuration (only when navigated to from `routerLink` or `router.navigate). Eager to be proven wrong ;-)

Comment: I am opening child view in popup and don't know how to pass params with it.

Comment: I have followed this http://onehungrymind.com/named-router-outlets-in-angular-2/

Comment: What about `['add-experience;param1=value1']` or `['add-experience?param1=value1']`? Link looks interesting. I'll try it.

Comment: here is the link of child view http://localhost:4200/my-account/(editDetail:add-experience)

Comment: can you show `AddExperienceComponent` template? do you have `router-outlet name="editDetail"` in it? why don't you put `path: 'add-experience/:id'` into the routing configuration?

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer is there really any provision to pass the data to named outlet?

Comment: I am showing AddExperienceComponent in parent component my-account by adding in my-account template <router-outlet name="editDetail"></router-outlet>

Comment: @micronyks I'd say the same as with other routes.

Comment: @harry above link is what you got for `['add-experience;param1=value1']`?

Comment: no with ['add-experience']  with ['add-experience;param1=value1'] there is error in console.

Comment: What error? I don't think this is what you want anyway. What you want are not optional route parameters. If you want to pass the `:id`, then this is not an optional route parameter, it's a normal route parameter and `['add-experience/someid']` should do what you want. If you want `:id` to be "optional", you need two routes one with and one without that parameter.

Comment: `{outlets: {'editDetail':['add-experience',{id:5}]}}` or `{outlets: {'editDetail':['add-experience', 5 ]}}`

Comment: yes ['add-experience/someid'] how it can be done then ? It's child of child

Comment: @micronyks Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'my-account'

Comment: Can you reproduce it using a plunker?

Comment: @micronyks thanks it worked :)

Comment: so what was the error?

Comment: @micronyks problem was in route it was add-experience/:id I make it add-experience now another problem is how to reinitialise child view it only loads first time ?

Comment: @micronyks I want to open views same like trello cards in popup